# replace window function in snowflake database to reduce query execution time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query which I am running on snowflake db. Below is the snowflake query.

```
Select
            TRIM(UPPER(SPLIT_PART(CPUNAME,'.',1))) AS "DCN",
            TRIM(STATUS) AS "Status"
             FROM    "DB"."HISTORY_mn"
    WHERE   OS LIKE '%Windows%'
    AND     (
                    TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows7'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows8'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'WindowsXp'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'WindowsCE'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows CE'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows2003'
            )
    AND     (
                    TRIM(UPPER(SPLIT_PART(CPUNAME,'.',1))) IS NOT NULL
                AND TRIM(UPPER(SPLIT_PART(CPUNAME,'.',1))) <> ''
            )
    AND     "Status" = 'Onboarded'
    AND     ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
    AND     DELETED_FLAG = 'N'    
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "DCN" ORDER BY EFF_TO_DATE DESC, EFF_FROM_DATE DESC, LASTSEEN DESC, FIRSTSEEN DESC) = 1
```

I checked the query profile .About 70% of the effort is consumed by window function.

- Total execution Time = 5 min 46 sec
- Total rows returned 19498.
- Total records in main table = 5.5 million

Statistics ::

- Scan progress
  100.00%
- Bytes scanned
  4.41GB
- Percentage scanned from cache
  71.89%
- Bytes written to result
  0.12MB
- Bytes sent over the network
  17.87GB
- Partitions scanned
  1962
- Partitions total
  1962
- Bytes spilled to local storage
  27.24GB

Is there a way we can tweak the query and better the performance?

Comment: If you just use the WHERE clause how many records does it return? If it is significantly less than the number of records in the table then it may be worth moving everything apart from the QUALIFY to a CTE and then your main query would just be a select from the CTE plus the qualify

Comment: @NickW, per OP, it is significantly less Total rows returned 19498. Total records in main table = 5.5 million.

Comment: And i think since you have 5mil in total data and its taking 5min to deduplicate it, i would say, try creating a intermediate table with only required columns and filters applied and then use qualify.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I was assuming that 19498 was after the qualify so it’s not clear if the significant reduction in rows is due to the WHERE, the QUALIFY, or a combination of both

Comment: The query is returing 19498 records, which is expected, the table history_mn has 5.5 million records. Hope it helps. Significant deduction is due to the whole query, I shared the numbers for ref. I cannot replcae qualify and window function with self join because CPU name is not unique

Comment: @VlogsBengali you seem to have missed the point of my question. Some of the reduction must be due to the WHERE clause and some must be due to the QUALIFY. If a significant proportion of the reduction is due to the WHERE clause then my previous suggestion may be worth trying

Comment: Hi @NickW .I got your point now, sorry. The entire reduction is due to where clause ,means 19498 rows are filterred from where. QUALIFY is not reducing any records , but its still needed as we might have more than 1 CPU name and we need the latest effective one. One update I tried to apply the solution from Aditya , by breaking down cte into filtered ctes and finally applying the qualify window func later, but it is not helping with performance  as aggregate operation in query profile is taking up around 40% of effort .Infact it is increasing execution time

Answer (score 0):

Try with below refactored query,

Here we pruned the data earlier instead of filtering all at same time based on static filter (exluding like) which does partition pruning more efficiently.

If this still does not improve performance significanly then

1. Create temporary table instead of CTE
2. Use warehouse with bigger size. As I can see 27.24GB data is spilled to local, it would be taking significal portion of time to send this to local and read again. Increasing warehouse size means more memory less spillage to local storage.

```
with filtered_data as (
        Select
            TRIM(UPPER(SPLIT_PART(CPUNAME,'.',1))) AS "DCN",
            TRIM(STATUS) AS "Status",
            OS,
            EFF_TO_DATE,
            EFF_FROM_DATE,
            LASTSEEN,
            FIRSTSEEN
        FROM    "DB"."HISTORY_mn"
        WHERE ifnull(TRIM(UPPER(SPLIT_PART(CPUNAME,'.',1))),'')<>''
            AND     "Status" = 'Onboarded'
            AND     ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
            AND     DELETED_FLAG = 'N' 
    )
select "DCN",
        "Status"
from filtered_data
where OS LIKE '%Windows%'
    AND     (
                    TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows7'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows8'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'WindowsXp'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'WindowsCE'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows CE'
                AND TRIM(OS) <> 'Windows2003'
            )
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "DCN" 
                    ORDER BY EFF_TO_DATE DESC, EFF_FROM_DATE DESC, LASTSEEN DESC, FIRSTSEEN DESC) = 1
```

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Performance-impact-from-local-and-remote-disk-spilling

Comment: spill local is not network traffic, (that is spill remote), but spilling from RAM to local disk (which disk is faster than network, but still slower than ram) But I agree the spill is a hint the current query's data needs are too large for this instances memory.

Comment: @ADITYA PAWAR I have applied filtered cte like you shared .But it is not helping with the performance .Most Expensive Nodes (8 of 22)
WindowFunction [7]
26.9%
Aggregate [14]
24.2%
WindowFunction [8]
16.1%
Join [9]
13.0%
Aggregate [5]
5.0%
WindowFunction [6]
4.5%
TableScan [15]
2.3%
WithReference [21]
2.2%
Profile Overview (Finished)
Total Execution Time
(5m 53s) 100.0%
Processing
47.3%
Local Disk I/O
7.0%
Remote Disk I/O
1.2%
Network Communication
35.6%
Synchronization
5.5%
Initialization

Comment: Did you tried running on bigger size warehouse?

Answer (score 0):

So Nick's question is (in long form):

there are 5.5M rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c 
FROM "DB"."HISTORY_mn"
WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
    AND DELETED_FLAG = 'N'
```

This is the number of rows that could be explicitly filtered and trigger partition pruning.

If this is 5.5M then that is not your cost.

Then there is the post dynamic filters, thus:

```
select 
    COUNT(*) as c 
FROM "DB"."HISTORY_mn"
WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
    AND DELETED_FLAG = 'N'  
    AND OS LIKE '%Windows%'
    AND TRIM(OS) not in ('Windows', 'Windows7', 'Windows8', 'WindowsXp', 'WindowsCE', 
        'Windows CE', 'Windows2003')
    AND TRIM(UPPER(SPLIT_PART(CPUNAME,'.',1))) IS NOT NULL 
    AND TRIM(UPPER(SPLIT_PART(CPUNAME,'.',1))) <> ''
    AND TRIM(STATUS) = 'Onboarded'
```

This is the number of rows going into the ROW_NUMBER, which might be the expensive section (this should be rather visible from the profile graph to be honest)..

So after the step if you have 100K rows, the row_count cannot be the 5 minuetes cost.

But these three queries now tell you, where the cost can be allocated, as there is a read, with static filters, and a dynamic filter, and then a row number. And really the ROW_NUMBER is the only part that needs all the data to be co-processed, so is likely the costly part.

And those three timing question can also be the structure for possible a faster way to run the query:

```
with static_filter as (
    select 
        TRIM(UPPER(SPLIT_PART(CPUNAME,'.',1))) AS DCN
        ,TRIM(STATUS) as "Status"
        ,OS
        ,EFF_TO_DATE
        ,EFF_FROM_DATE
        ,LASTSEEN
        ,FIRSTSEEN
    FROM "DB"."HISTORY_mn"
    WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
        AND DELETED_FLAG = 'N'  
        AND OS LIKE '%Windows%'
), filter2 as (
    SELECT      
        DCN
        ,"Status"
        ,EFF_TO_DATE
        ,EFF_FROM_DATE
        ,LASTSEEN
        ,FIRSTSEEN
    FROM static_filter
    WHERE OS LIKE '%Windows%'
        AND TRIM(OS) not in ('Windows', 'Windows7', 'Windows8', 'WindowsXp', 'WindowsCE', 'Windows CE', 'Windows2003')
        AND DCN IS NOT NULL 
        AND DCN <> ''
        AND "Status" = 'Onboarded'
)
SELECT 
    DCN,
    "Status"
FROM filter2
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "DCN" ORDER BY EFF_TO_DATE DESC, EFF_FROM_DATE DESC, LASTSEEN DESC, FIRSTSEEN DESC) = 1;
```

albeit the last two steps can be merged like you have it.